# Is there a way to split an object by vertex index?

Tags: vertices

I used umodel to rip models from an unreal engine game. However, it put a lot of meshes in one object. So, I have a black hole of 22k verts that all belong to like 40+ items. The good thing, is that the items can be separated by vertex index. Like, verts 0-277 are a model, verts 278-569 are a model. Is there a way I can split a model based on vertex indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use <kbd>P</kbd> -> **By Loose Parts** in edit mode. This operation separates vertexes that connected to each outer by edges.

Comment: That kind of works, but each gun has several parts when pieced like this, so its kind of impossible to solve this jigsaw puzzle haha